# Angularjs requests failing after inactivity

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web app using AngularJS 1.28 and I noticed that after a period of inactivity all requests to the server fail and the web app stops responding normally. This includes any ajax request on the same view or even switching between views (e.g., can't change views after a period of inactivity).

I manage to reproduce the issue on a android phone using Chrome. After refreshing the page it is all back to normal.

Is this a known issue? What can be done to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specifics on the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Hix Lux, i know the ajax request are being done but it's like they timeout and nothing happens. Is angularjs unloaded after a period of inactivity?

Comment: That's interesting behavior, and no, AngularJS should not become unresponsive after a period of inactivity - I would pop open the browser console (typically via F12), as well as check the server logs for any errors.

Comment: Hi Lux, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on the desktop so no developer tools. Tried again on the mobile but not either while reproducing the issue...